# Java Policy file as an argument to Process Builder

Tags: java, processbuilder, policyfiles

I am using a simple way to implement a custom policy file, which works fine when implemented via cmd.

```
   List < String > paramsExecute = new ArrayList < String > ();
      paramsExecute.add("java");
      paramsExecute.add("-cp");
      paramsExecute.add(Path); 
      paramsExecute.add("dummy."+packageName);
      paramsExecute.add("-Djava.security.manager");
    paramsExecute.add("-Djava.security.policy=C:\\full\\path\\MyPolicyFile.policy");

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(paramsExecute);
```

I have checked the classPath.No Exception is thrown, but the policy file is not implemented, where is the Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments before the main class name are interpreted by the JVM. Arguments after the main class name are passed to the program - the JVM doesn't look at them.

This order of parameters should work - note that all the options are before the main class name:

```
List < String > paramsExecute = new ArrayList < String > ();
paramsExecute.add("java");
paramsExecute.add("-cp");
paramsExecute.add(Path); 
paramsExecute.add("-Djava.security.manager");
paramsExecute.add("-Djava.security.policy=C:\\full\\path\\MyPolicyFile.policy");
paramsExecute.add("dummy."+packageName);
```

Comment: One more thing, if I remember correctly `ArrayList` do not guarantee the same order of arguments. Better to use a `LinkedList`?

Comment: @joeyrohan That is incorrect. All Lists maintain their order.